# Is there a way to put a python turtle game on web?

Tags: python, html, turtle-graphics

I recently just made a python game using the turtle graphics library:

https://repl.it/@Cyh1368/30-something

and I am willing to put it on a website. Is there any way to do that? For example, add some elements to the html file?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://docs.repl.it/repls/embed

Comment: you can put link to file with code and people can download it. Web browser can run only JavaScript so you can't run Python code on page directly. Eventually you could try Python's interpreter create in JavaScript or tools which can convert Python to JavaScript: [transcrypt](https://www.transcrypt.org/), [brython](https://brython.info/), [skulpt](https://skulpt.org/), [trinket](https://trinket.io/python)

Comment: @jtbandes I’ve never heard of that! I think it’ll help!